# Is it possible to implement filter using foldl instead of foldr?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is it possible to implement filter using foldl instead of foldr? If so, please explain your implementation gently.

Comment: To add to this, I'm glad I dared to ask and learned something new today (difference lists). It's worth the shame! ;)

Comment: Answer as a comment, since it's closed: No, it's impossible, well, sort of. `filter` can produce output when given an infinite list, `foldl` can't. So you'd have to chunk your input and use the foldl-filter chunk-wise, concatenating the results. For treating finite lists, hammar's solution is the least inefficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer tnx for adding this

Comment: For finite lists, foldr can be written in terms of foldl: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldl_as_foldr

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Not a real question? Difficult to tell what is being asked? Cannot be reasonably answered? None of those descriptions fit this question. If you want to close a question, pick a real reason. If none of the close reasons that SO gives fit the question, that suggests that SO policy is that the question *should not be closed*, and you should start a discussion on meta if you feel the policy should be changed.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Please vote to reopen this question. It is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [difference lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list):

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p xs = foldl (\k x -> if p x then k . (x:) else k) id xs []
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer and introducing me with difference lists. Really learned a new concept by asking this question.

Comment: `filter' even [1 .. ]`. `foldl` _never_ can produce anything when fed an infinite list.

Answer (score 3):

Not really efficiently if you want to keep the order of the list. The naive approach is to just change it into foldl and then reverse the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

Came up with this one:

```
myFilter p coll =
  foldl step [] coll where 
    step acc e  
      | p e = acc ++ [e] 
      | otherwise = acc
```

It's not really efficient, since it has to insert one element at the end of a list.